# Customize devportal for WSO2 3.1.0

Tags: wso2

I am unable to customize the devportal to suit our corporate needs. [wso2 3.1.0 documenttion](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/consume-api/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/overriding-developer-portal-theme/)  says that we can change defaultTheme.js found in devportal/source/src . But no changes to that file are reflected on the browser. Even if I make the file blank, the home page still shows default content. And it is not acache issue because I have cleared the browser. It seems the actual files for modifying the look and feel of devportal are hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Source file /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/source/src/defaultTheme.js is there only for the reference. 
You can override the parameters defined in the above file from /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/site/public/theme/defaultTheme.js